# Unable to view partition table in a schema

Tags: oracle, partitioning, oracle-11g, table

I am using oracle 11g enterprise edition,

I have created a schema as "TESTSCHEMA"  and in it i have created a partition table as "sales_test".

The query for the table,

```
create table sales_test (year number(4),
                    product varchar2(10),
                   amt number(10,2))
     partition by range (year)
     (partition p1 values less than (1992),
     partition p2 values less than (1993),
     partition p3 values less than (1994),
     partition p4 values less than (1995),
   partition p5 values less than (MAXVALUE));
```

The problem is, 
After creating the table it does not display the table from dbvisualiser, but it can display unpartitioned tables.

[image]

I have created one user of my own as `MDR_139` and it has `ALL PRIVILEGES` like what DBA has.

Answer (score 1):

If you created the table with the above statement as user `MDR_139`, then that table belongs to the `MDR_139` schema, not `TESTSCHEMA`.

If you want to create tables in other schemas, add the schema specifier to the create statement, for example:

```
create table TESTSCHEMA.sales_test (year number(4),
                    product varchar2(10),
                   amt number(10,2))
     partition by range (year)
     (partition p1 values less than (1992),
     partition p2 values less than (1993),
     partition p3 values less than (1994),
     partition p4 values less than (1995),
   partition p5 values less than (MAXVALUE));
```